# start setInterval before page load

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Is there a way to start the interval before `window.onload`, or other events like `document.readystate loading`?

I want the interval starts before everything.. I'm trying some experiment:

http://jsfiddle.net/nv7Rh/

http://jsfiddle.net/Wy3JN/

---

**Update** This starts the timer interval from a script placed in the body monitoring the the image loading, then the `window.load` stop it:

jsfiddle /nv7Rh/1/

This happens if the image is not loaded in the cache, so I clear the cache for retest.

Now I am ok

Comment: If you don't assume some element exists there is no reason not to start an interval sooner (other than the possible cascading of intervals)

Comment: how ever I am still confused about the order of events: http://jsfiddle.net/w4h5j/ If I change the order of them, the result changes...

Answer (score 0):

You can start a setInterval in code that executes before DOMContentReady (the first load event, indicating that the document has been parsed), provided it's in an inline script tag or non-async external script. Async scripts can be run before the later onload event (which runs when all resources have been parsed).

If you need the interval to reference functions defined in non-blocking scripts, you can set up a handler array that you can register functions against, that the interval will lookup and execute every time it runs.

Comment: i'm not expert, i'm new in javascript.. please can you show some example?

Answer (score 0):

Just run your interval function outside of those functions. If you don't think the element is loaded yet, just make sure your code checks if that element exists before doing anything, e.g. don't just:

```
document.querySelector(".foo").doSomething();
```

but:

```
var foo = document.querySelector(".foo"); foo && foo.doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can very well start an interval before any page events. Just start it from code that is not inside the event handler.

However, if you want to update something in the page from the interval handler, you have to wait until there is a page to update. If you for example use `getElementById` to locate an element to update, you should check if you get a null reference back as that means that the element doesn't exist yet.

Example:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  var clock = document.getElementById('clock');
  if (clock != null) {
    clock.innerHTML = new Date().toString();
  }
}, 100);
```